# PHP not being able to pick data from HTML form

Tags: php, html

My PHP page is unable to pick values from HTML form. It's sending blank strings to database. Here is my HTML and PHP code. Please find error. I am new to PHP, unable to solve the problem.

```
my html page:
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html >
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">

       <title>LOGIN</title>



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">


      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'>

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">






      </head>



    <body>



    <!-- Mixins-->
    <!-- Pen Title-->

    <div class="pen-title">

    <h1>SYNCHPHONY</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="rerun"><a href="">Rerun Pen</a></div>
    <div class="container">

     <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card">

       <h1 class="title">Login</h1>

     <form name="login" action="login.php" method="POST">

        <div class="input-container">

       <input type="text" id="loginid" required="required"/>


     <label for="loginid">Login ID</label>

        <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>

      <div class="input-container">


      <input type="password" id="password" required="required"/>

         <label for="password">Password</label>

      <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>

       <div class="button-container">

      <button><span>Go</span></button>
          </div>


      </form>

      </div>

    <div class="card alt">
        <div class="toggle"></div>

      <h1 class="title">Register

    <div class="close"></div>
        </h1>

       <form name="register" action="register.php" method="POST">

     <div class="input-container">

         <input type="text" id="loginid" required="loginid"/>

        <label for="loginid">Login ID</label>

    <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>

        <div class="input-container">

        <input type="password" id="password" required="required"/>

     <label for="password">Password</label>

     <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>


    <div class="button-container">

        <button value'submitb'><span>Next</span></button>
          </div>

      </form>

     </div>
    </div>


        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

            <script src="js/index.js"></script>



      </body>
    </html>

my php page:

**strong text**    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "syncphony";
    $loginid="";
    $password="";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    if(isset($_POST['loginid'])){ $loginid = $_POST['loginid']; }
    if(isset($_POST['password'])){ $password = $_POST['password']; }

    // Escape user inputs for security
    $loginid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$loginid);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (loginid, password ) VALUES ('$loginid', '$password')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Side note: **NEVER** store passwords in plain text format. You should save them as an md5() hash for example. When the user logs in - convert the password to a hash client side, and send the **hash** in the request for comparison with the server side value.

Comment: Maybe you want to give your inputs a name, not just id?

Comment: you havn't declare name attribute. $_POST['loginid'] . "loginid" should be name not id in the input filed.

Comment: @MacroMan: **NEVER** store your passwords in MD5 hash format, store them using Bcrypt for example. MD5 should be regarded as essentially broken at this point.

Comment: @halfer "for example" - Purely because it was the first hash type that came to mind. I'm not an encryption expert by any means.

Comment: @MacroMan: genuinely I mean no offence, but it was an incorrect example. Someone would use unsalted MD5 hashing based on that piece of advice, and we need to make sure they do not do that.

Comment: @halfer if you get a chance, would you mind dropping in the VBA Lounge chat room and drop me a link to explain why? I don't use it at the moment, but in the near future I am going to have to store passwords as part of some work I'm doing so would rather know now than later...

Answer (score 1):

The `input`s inside your `form` tag do not have `name`s. Try this for login:

```
<input type="text" id="loginid" required="required" name="loginid"/>
```

and this for password:

```
<input type="password" id="password" required="required" name="password"/>
```

It would be nice if you would protect your users against [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) and to use [encryption](http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html) when you store a password. Also, you should structure your code and make sure your HTML is valid.

Comment: Don't know how this hasn't had an upvote - never mind not being accepted... +1